# Getting virtuemart price at the template

Tags: joomla, helper, virtuemart

I'm new in joomla and I'm getting crazy because as I wanna get the price (and another metadata) of a product at the template just using the ID of the product, does anyboy could tell me how getting it, perhaps with a **helper** o **static method** or **instanciating a class**? (I have googled it). It's Virtuemart 1.1.3 and joomla 1.5.10.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A little information about versions, and what you've attempted would be very helpful.

Comment: You are true. I have added this data.

Comment: Better, but all you've said is "I wanna get...".  No indication of where you want it, or what's to be done with it - my first reaction is "look in the database, there it is".  And again, a sample of what you've tried.  We don't write your code here, we help you work out problems that you encounter while doing it.

Comment: You are true, sorry, I'm getting mad with it. I just corrected this.

Answer (score 0):

Still not clear on where you're wanting to use it, but if it's from within VM that you want to get the product information, there are a number of places you can look at and see if it suits what you're trying to accomplish:

**Virtuemart Custom Theme.php**

Found at `components\com_virtuemart\themes\default\theme.php`.  Allows you to write custom functions to access anything in VM for your own use.

```
/**
* This is the theme's function file.
* It allows you to declare additional functions and classes
* that may be used in your templates
*
```

**Browse Results on Flypage**

The search/browse saves many product fields - they're saved into an array near the end of `html\show.browse.php` (look for `$products[$i]['product_price'] = $product_price;`) , then loaded into the VM templates with `$tpl->set( 'products', $products )` , and finally, used when rendering the product fly page